# NoSQL fast simple mass-data store

Tags: mysql, nosql, couchdb, redis

Just looking into some noSQL alternatives to improve our data-store system, currently utilizing MySQL. Basically looking for a super-fast data accumulation.

Features that we are after are being able to read data from large data-store (with static queries), many inserts per minute (about 50 per min, but needs to scale well), not a huge need to update data.

After reading [this](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis/) article, i'm leaning towards Redis or CouchDB. Any thoughts or suggestions? Happy to give more information if needed...

Comment: NoSQL isn't an alternative to MySQL, it's an alternative to SQL. Alternatives to MySQL would be *other* SQL implementations like PostgreSQL or MS-SQL. You appear to be looking for an *alternative* to relational databases.

Comment: Oops, thanks for pointing that out..bad comparison! Basically, our current system is overly complex and convoluted for what we are trying to achieve. I believe it can be done quicker and far more efficient with a NoSQL alternative. For example, all we need to store is a dataset along the lines of ... {'name': 'input', 'type': 'special', 'value': 2.342}. Our MySQL tables have this information split over several tables (not to mention now useless info), which is a little painful..

Comment: then just de-normalize your data if it doesn't need to be in multiple tables, NoSQL alternatives won't make poor database designs any better.

Comment: 50 inserts per minute isn't much - is that really what you meant? Many of the NoSQL solutions can do thousands of inserts per _second_.

Comment: That's only what we're currently at. Basically, we want the freedom to scale up to thousands of inserts per minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CouchDB has excellent write performance, given that it's an append-only write database. Since your queries are static, they will fit in nicely with CouchDB's map-reduce view system. In addition, views are calculated incrementally, being very fast and efficient to keep up to date.

Unfortunately, I can't speak much to Redis, but I can tell you that CouchDB sounds like a nice fit based on your list of features.

Comment: CouchDB really does sound like a good fit for my purpose..have also been looking into MongoDB, but I think I'll try out the couch! The issue I have with Redis, is that it keeps the entire database in RAM,which isn't ideal for my situation (there'll be potentially years worth of data). Thanks!

Comment: You might also want to give RavenDB a look

Answer (score 3):

CouchDB is extremely fast for static queries. By design it stores the result of the query as an index. Any results can be obtained in like O(log n) time. Read [this](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/btree.html) to know why CouchDb extremely fast. For example it has been deployed by [CERN](http://www.readwriteweb.com/enterprise/2010/08/lhc-couchdb.php) to manage huge write data (10PB/Yr). Also its quiet simple to pick up. Apart from the official wiki, [this](http://guide.couchdb.org/index.html) will suffice for basic CouchDb.

Comment: Thanks @Vipin, have actually been looking at that today, great resource! I've dived right into the Couch, and just getting my head around the new way of thinking (document-based rather than table based).